# Logic Apps SharePoint Connector - Move file with new file name

Tags: azure-logic-apps

We have a integration requirement to move files from one folder to another in SharePoint Online. The new file name in the destination folder needs to be suffixed with the current datetime. For instance, if the source filename is **Myfile.csv**, it should be moved with the new name **Myfile_2021-04-15T15:39:23.csv** to the destination folder.

Using the Logic App SharePoint Move file action, I haven't been able to achieve this
[image]

*If another file is already there* is an enum and I'm unable to provide a custom expression for it. Further, with this option files are only renamed if there's a file with the same name already existing in the destination folder. Whereas our requirement is to attach datetime to all files that are being transferred, independent whether the file already exist in the destination folder or not.

How can I best achieve this?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the "**Move file**" action doesn't provide a feature for us to specify the new file name, I think the requirement can't be implemented by this action. You can just use other action to do it.

For example, use "**Get file content**" action to get the file content.

[image]

Then use "**Create file**" action to create the new file in the location which you want.

[image]

You can specify a name which you want in the "**File name**" input box.

By the way, the "**Get file content**" action doesn't provide an expression of file name for us to use in second step. But I noticed that you have got `Full path` in your description, so you can substring the `Full path` to get the original file name. And then use `utcNow()` method to get the current date and append it to file name.